# Не доступны элементы, в которые оборачиваю элемент

Tags: javascript, jquery

Появился вопрос, почему я не вижу **span**'ы в которые обернул текст? Если добавлять через append, к примеру, то все гут, а тут нет.

```js
$("li").wrapInner("span");
$("span").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3):

Вы немного неправильно используете метод [wrapInner](https://jquery-docs.ru/wrapInner/).
В документации написано - Тип: htmlString or Selector or jQuery or Element.
А вы отправляете строку 'span', которая является селектором, но элементов с таким селектором у вас нет.

**htmlString**

```js
$("li").wrapInner("<span></span>");
$("span").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

**Element**

```js
$("li").wrapInner(document.createElement('span'));
$("span").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

**Selector**

```js
$("li").wrapInner('span');
$("span").on("click", function() {
  alert($(this).html());
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span></span>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

**jQuery** то же самое, что **Element**, но обернутое в jQuery

Comment: Ну вот из документации и не могу понять в чем проблема, поэтому пришёл сюда.

Comment: @wind обновил ответ, стало понятнее?

Comment: Действительно, упустил момент с тем что указывал селектор, пытался работать как с document.createElement, Спасибо за помощь!